# How to code a custom Comparator to sort a Treeset with SimpleEntry?

Tags: java, tree, comparator

I'm currently working on an assignement which requires me to use a Treeset to sort pairs of value. I'm asked to use SimpleEntry. I'm storing them on a Treeset :

```java
    TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet(new PairComparator());
    SimpleEntry pair = new SimpleEntry(weight,source);
    treeSet.add(pair);
```

Here is my custom Comparator :

```java
static class PairComparator implements Comparator<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> {

        @Override
        public int compare(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,Integer> o1, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,Integer> o2) {
            int key1 = o1.getKey() ;
            int key2 = o2.getKey();
            return key1 - key2;
        }
    }
```

I get an error I don't understand, which is :

> class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer

Could you explain me what is happening? I'm not totally familiar with defining a custom comparator.

Thanks for your attention !

**EDIT :** I was adding a Hashmap as a key on my SimpleEntry and not an integer, which is now quite obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like somehow you have added a HashMap as a key to one of the SimpleEntries in your TreeSet.

Show a complete runnable example please.

This code works for me:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    static class PairComparator implements Comparator<SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> {

        @Override
        public int compare(SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> o1, SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
            int key1 = o1.getKey();
            int key2 = o2.getKey();
            return key1 - key2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet(new PairComparator());
        treeSet.add(new SimpleEntry(42, 69));
        treeSet.add(new SimpleEntry(37, 65));
        treeSet.add(new SimpleEntry(23, 19));
        treeSet.add(new SimpleEntry(54, 12));
        System.out.println(treeSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right I mistyped pair. I add it on my Treeset indeed. 
This code is part of an implementation of a Dijkstra algorithm using Treeset. The code is somewhat similar to this one : https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dijkstra-algorithm-implementation-treeset-and-pair-class/. But instead of using Pair, I'm trying to use SimpleEntry. The key for my SimpleMap is the weight of an edge and the value is the index of the source vertex.

Comment: I tried your code but I still have the same issue. Here is the error code : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.util.HashMap and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Comment: @Winver I've run the example without issues. I am using JDK 15.  I've added imports to clarify what classes are being used.  There is no use of HashMap in my code.  Did you run my example as-is?

Comment: I found my mistake, I wasn't putting an Integer on my SimpleEntry key...
I feel so stupid making this mistake. I was adding a Hashmap instead of taking the value the given key which is exactly what you were saying... Thanks for your answer ! Your code totally works because I tried on an other file. All good !

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the types for the `TreeSet` and some other data structures but I did it here and it works just fine.  I did change your comparator.  Subtracting integer values to do the comparisons is not a good idea as it can cause problems for large numbers.

```
        
TreeSet<SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> treeSet =
        new TreeSet<>(new PairComparator());

Random r = new Random(23);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int weight = r.nextInt(100);
    int source = r.nextInt(100);
    
    SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> pair =
            new SimpleEntry<>(weight, source);
    treeSet.add(pair);
}

treeSet.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints the following (duplicate keys ignored)

```
18=43
22=17
24=30
27=48
81=95
83=47
89=70
90=10
94=87
```

The comparator

```
static class PairComparator implements
        Comparator<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> {
    public int compare(
            AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> o1,
            AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
        int key1 = o1.getKey();
        int key2 = o2.getKey();
        return key1 < key2 ? -1 : key1 > key2 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

You can also specify the following as a comparator.

```
Comparator<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,Integer>> pairComparator =
     (se1,se2)-> Integer.compare(se1.getKey(),se2.getKey());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! IntelliJ tells me it could be simplified as `Integer.compare(key1, key2);` which works as well, but I have to use the `key1 - key2` return statement. So thanks for your insight !

Comment: I'm curious why you have to use `key1-key2`?  It is really considered bad practice?  You could also use  ternary operator.

Comment: I'm here storing pairs of "distance,vertex" on a treeset where we need to store each pairs by ascending ordering so we can retrieve the vertex with the smallest distance first. I guess the code given could be enhanced and can't explain why the teacher decided to do it this way. Keys here are integers and not too big. (But in reality keys which are weights could take double values with decimals so I totally agree it's not the best way to do it). Do you think we could adapt it by replacing Integers by Double for exemple?

Comment: You should be able to easily switch over to doubles.